# AdSense not displaying on my blog

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense, content

Recently I started to work again with AdSense program, but when I placed code in my WordPress blog it didn't display even after 30min.
So maybe I'm doing something wrong?
I did setup the account.
Created ad for content.
Got the code.
Placed it in my themes sidebar.

Maybe I have to add my webpage address somewhere or it takes more time to start displaying adds?
Thank you all for help.

Comment: Note the link in the other answer is a more complete solution to the problem than mine is, so that might be a better accepted answer.

Comment: @Kinopiko Yes. Link is good, but you explained on the words and this is better. Either way the one who will read this post will find the link too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, I won't insult your intelligence by saying "You did turn off Adblock, didn't you?", because it's probably only me that forgets about that kind of thing.

Next possibility: Is your blog actually on a public-facing server or is it on a test machine? If it's on a test machine like http://localhost/ then Google might not send the ads. Note that the Google ad robot comes to your page to have a look and decide what ads to put there, and you'll end up with public service ads if it can't see the page.

Third time lucky: I think they say somewhere that it takes ten minutes but sometimes it can take longer. I'd give it a day or two - you probably weren't going to break the bank in that time anyway.

If none of the above does the trick, I'd try making an ultra-simple HTML page like

```
<html>
<body>
<google ad here>
</body>
</html>
```

and see if that works on your site. If that doesn't work, then I'd contact Google.

Comment: First one is about me :( I didn't know, that FF AdBlock Pluss automaticaly blocks Google AdSense without even asking about it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it normal, that I asked my friend to click once on one link just to test, doest it work or not, but in reports there is no data about, that click?

Comment: Adsense data isn't instant and real-time, it may be 2 days before you see the results.

Comment: @Eugene: is your friend using the same computer or network as you? Google probably assumed it was an accidental self-click. Please don't ask your friends to click on adsense links, since Google will kick you off their program for doing that. Also, never post things like "please click on the links to help this site" since Google will kick you off their program for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [wizard at the Adsense site to troubleshoot this issue](http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/request.py?contact=troubleshooter_CSA)

Comment: That's a good link.